# How to pass the value of a jmeter response as the input to the next request

Tags: jmeter

As am new to jmeter please help me in passing the value from a webservice response as the input to the next webservice request

Comment: this is not the correct way to ask question dear,before asking a question,do reasearch on your question first,also tell that,what you got in that research.then post a question,and do read fAQ before asking a question

Answer (score 3):

I guess that your web service returns XML (more likely) or JSON.

All you need is to use [XPath Extractor Post Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0), get interesting response part, store it to variable and use in next request.

You can address variables next ways:

1. ${YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME}
2. ${__V(YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME)}

I prefer the second option as it allows combining several variables, evaluating functions, etc.